# Jquery + CSS to show/hide table elements based on viewport width size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'd appreciate if someone could advise on my problem.
My code on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nepovx0e/4/)

I have the list of models and corresponding values that change across several categories. I have a simple table that shows this data. However, I need to change table structure when my viewport width is `<=640 px`, to show only 1 category and make it clickable, so that values could change.

My problem occurs when I resize the screen. When my screen size is  `<=640 px` and I click on category (values are changing) and resize back to bigger screen size, my table should show all values again. I would be grateful if you can help me with some jquery fixes.

**JS:**

```
$('a.cashback-btn').click(function(event) {
  if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
    $('.cashback-block .cash-table').slideUp('fast');
    $(this).find('i').removeClass("fa-chevron-up");
    $(this).find('i').addClass("fa-chevron-down");
    $(this).removeClass('active');
  } else {
    $('.cashback-block .cash-table').slideDown('fast');
    $(this).find('i').removeClass("fa-chevron-down");
    $(this).find('i').addClass("fa-chevron-up");
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $('a.cashback-btn').offset().top
    }, 1000);
  }
});

var medalsCnt = 1; // 1-3, 4-6, 7-10, >10
var medalsMsg = "1-3 category";
$('.cash-table th.mobile').click(function() {
  medalsCnt++;
  $('.cashback-block table td:not(:first-child)').hide();
  if (medalsCnt == 2) {
    medalsMsg = "4-6 category";
    $('.cashback-block table td:nth-child(3)').show();
  } else if (medalsCnt == 3) {
    medalsMsg = "7-10 category";
    $('.cashback-block table td:nth-child(4)').show();
  } else if (medalsCnt == 4) {
    medalsMsg = "more 10 category";
    $('.cashback-block table td:nth-child(5)').show();
  }
  if (medalsCnt > 4) {
    medalsCnt = 1;
    medalsMsg = "1-3 category";
    $('.cashback-block table td:nth-child(2)').show();
  }
  $(this).find('span').text(medalsMsg);
});
```

**UPDATE**

```
$( window ).resize(function () {
     if($('.mobile-version').is(":visible")){
        return; //need to show/hide only one column based on category selected
     }
     else{
        $('.cashback-block table td').show(); //works ok, but now mobile version is not working
     }
  });
```

Comment: Which part of resize code are you having the issue?

Comment: Please see my update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following changes in your code hope so it will work.

```
$(window).resize(function(ev) {
    console.log(ev);
    if ($('.mobile-version').is(":visible")) {
        return; //need to show/hide only one column based on category selected
    } else {
    }
          if($(window).width()<=640){
            $('.cashback-block table td:not(:first-child)').hide();
            $('.cashback-block table td:nth-child('+(medalsCnt+1)+')').show(); //works ok, but now mobile version is not working                
        }else{
            $('.cashback-block table td').show();
        }
});
```

JS Fiddle for this is https://jsfiddle.net/nepovx0e/7/

Answer (score 1):

```
var wW = $(window).width();
if(wW <= 640){
    // get tr that you want to be clickable
    // add event click
        // run code
}
```

Use media queries from css to change the style of the table. Hide all the table rows that you don't want to appear.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you check for window width and also use another  variable to bind the event only once. If you do not check this the same event will be attached to the element as many times as you resize the width less than 640 px.

```
var eventBind == false
if ($(window).width() <= 640 && eventBind == false) 
    { 
     // now bind your event here.
     eventBind  = true;
}
```